# Full process name from task_struct

Tags: linux, process, kernel

I want to get full process name from `struct task_struct`. The `comm` field stores only 16 characters, while process name can be longer. Is there any way to get full process name? 
This can be done through by getting `struct vm_area_struct` from `task_struct`, and further obtain file to which vm_area is mapped, but this is unreliable.

Comment: Is it unreliable? That's exactly what the proc filesystem does to return a path in `/proc/<pid>/exe`. Search the kernel source for `proc_exe_link`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you mean exe file name? You can get the exe of current process as follows :

```
char *pathname,*p;
mm = current->mm;
if (mm) {
    down_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
    if (mm->exe_file) {
                pathname = kmalloc(PATH_MAX, GFP_ATOMIC);
                if (pathname) {
                      p = d_path(&mm->exe_file->f_path, pathname, PATH_MAX);
                    /*Now you have the path name of exe in p*/
                }
            }
    up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`current->nameidata->filename->name` should also work.

Answer (score -3):

Just use `current->comm` and you can see the name.

Example:

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "THREAD NAME = %s\n", current->comm);
```

Comment: I believe the downvotes are because `comm[]` is not a proper string, but a 16 byte character array which might not be '\0' terminated. The code provided here has a read-out-of-bounds issue, and in addition it doesn't answer the OP's question (16 byte limit).

Comment: I might have been wrong about '\0' termination in my previous comment.